# How to tell redux to set a certain value only if it's equal to action.id

Tags: reactjs, redux

How would i tell redux to filter through `state.posts`, and if `post.id` is equivalent to action.id set the value of likes for that specific post.

as of now, the number of likeCounts on all posts are all set to a number like 17. **When it should be post 1 has 17 likes, post 2 has 5 likes, etc.**

`console.log(action.data) // logs number of likes for all posts`

does not render an array just single values like this

[image]

[image]

**reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[],
    isEditing:false,
    isEditingId:null,
    likes:0,
    postId:null
}

     case GET_LIKES_COUNT:
            console.log(action.data) // logs number of likes for all posts 
                                     // (line 45)
            console.log(state.posts) // logs an array of posts
            console.log(action.id) // logs post id 
            // need to check if post.id is === action.id if so give it the value from action.data
            return({
                ...state,
                likes: action.data 
            })
```

Comment: Will a simple if/else not work? `if(post.id === action.id) { return .... } else { return .... }`

Comment: Im unsure how to write an if statement within a reducer. state.posts would need to be using the `filter` method then `post.id` would become available.

Comment: how would you write it :) ?

Comment: Where do you keep the number of likes for a given post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simply use if else statement or ternary operators in reducers. Just keep in mind the immutability factor as state should never be mutated otherwise it creates problem further. For that purpose you can use immutability helpers of redux.

```
const initialState = {
        post: [],
        postError: null,
        posts:[],
        isEditing:false,
        isEditingId:null,
        likes:0,
        postId:null
    }



case GET_LIKES_COUNT:
let newState = [...state].post.map(post => post.id === action.id ? post.likes === action.data : post); // for immutability purpose
            return({
                newState
            })
```

Comment: how is post.id being accessed ? Wouldn't you need to use `state.posts.map( (post) )`  ?

Comment: Yah right. Thanks for correcting and there are many ways of setting state, you can combine reducers and configure store

Comment: i see that you edited this, was their any reason why you would not use map or filter ? being that state.posts is an array ? just trying to see things in a different perspective

Comment: If your post is an array of object does it consist property likes. So that I can change likes of that specific post

Comment: not sure if that is a question or the reason why you choose to do it the way you did it. Will use this solution and let you know how it went. thanks for the assistance :)

Comment: This will not work wait for 2 mins just tell me 2 things what does action contains ? Does it contain both id and data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192269/discussion-between-deepankar-singh-and-mr-patel).

Answer (score 0):

A better way to fetch likes from a post would be to include it in your backend api call `myPosts`.

like this

```
router.get('/myPosts',  async  (req, res) =>{
   await models.Post.findAll({ 
        include:[{
            model:models.Likes
        }],    
        order:[ 
        ['createdAt', 'DESC'],
        ], limit: 6 })
       .then( (posts) =>{
           res.json(posts);

       })
});
```

that way only that specific post, will fetch number of likes for that post.

and it can be called like this

PostItem.js

```
....
<Like like={id} likes={Likes.length} />
```

**Like.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee, faAdjust } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {  getLikeCount, postLike} from '../actions/';
class Like extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            likes: null,
            heart: false
        }
    }

    clickLike = (id) => {
        this.props.postLike(id);
        // toggles between css class
        this.setState({
            heart: !this.state.heart
        })
    }
    render(){
       return(
            <div style={{float:'right', fontSize: '1.5em', color:'tomato'}} >
            <i style={{ marginRight: '140px'}} className={this.state.heart ? 'fa fa-heart':'fa fa-heart-o' }>
                    <span style={{ marginLeft: '6px'}}>
                        <a href="#" onClick={ () => this.clickLike(this.props.like)}>Like</a>       
                    </span>
                    {/* gets the like counts */}
                    {this.props.likes}
                </i>
            </div>       
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    likeCount:state.post.likes
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id))

});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Like);
```